# Derivatives of Higher Order

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $f : U \to  \mathbb{R}$. The
  function $f$ is said to be in $C^k(U)$, if $f$ has all continuous
  partial derivatives up to and including order $k$ on $U$. Let $l \le
  k$ and $i_1, i_2, \dots, i_l$ be a collection of integers between
  $1$ and $l$. Under these conditions, show that for any permutation
  $\sigma \in S_l$, we have
$
D_{i_1, \dots, i_l} f = D_{\sigma (i_1), \dots, \sigma (i_l)} f.
$

I know how to prove this result if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ i.e., $D_{12}f = D_{21}f$. Is induction the way to prove it for the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All permutations on the set $\{1,2,...,l\}$ can be written as a product of $(12),(23),...,((j-1)j)$. So this general question can be reduced to the case $D_{i_1, \dots, i_l} f =D_{i_1, \dots,i_{j-1},i_{j+1},i_j,i_{j+2},\cdots i_l} f$. For this special case, note that $D_{i_1, \dots, i_l} f =D_{i_1, \dots,i_{j-1}}(D_{i_j,i_{j+1}}(D_{i_{j+2},\cdots i_l}f))$.

I use $(ij)$ to denote the bijection on $\{1,2,...,l\}$ which sends $i$ to $j$ and $j$ to $i$. This is a standard notation, you could refer to [wiki: symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I do not understand the first statement of your proof.

Comment: @saurav90 I've added a remark. Can you understand now?

Comment: I am reading baby Rudin and do not have an algebra background. Is it possible to present an explanation without resorting to algebra.

Comment: @saurav90 Let $\sigma$ be a permutation on the (index) set  $\{1,2,...,l\}$, and $\sigma_i$ ($i=1,2,\cdots,l-1$) denote the permutation on $\{1,2,...,l\}$ which interchanges $i,i+1$ and leave other elements fixed. Then a fundamental result is that $\sigma$ can always be written as $\sigma_{i(1)}\circ\sigma_{i(2)}\circ\cdots\circ\sigma_{i(r)}$ where $i(1),i(2),\cdots,i(r)$ take values in $\{1,2,...,l\}$. The prove is not so hard but quite long, can you image it?

Comment: Could you please tell what is the name of this fundamental result on permutations. I think I got the proof.

Comment: @saurav90 I don't think this result has a name. In fact, much fewer results in algebra admit their own names than analysis. But I'm sure you will meet it as long as you get started to learn linear algebra.

Comment: @CensiLI: Can you present a proof for that?

Comment: @Silvermoon I can give a hint. The whole proof is too long: Given a permutation $i_1i_2\cdots i_n$of $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$, if there is a certain $k$ such that $i_k>k$, then interchange $i_k$ with $i_{k-1}$, applying this operation repeatedly, we will get $12\cdots n$ at last.

Comment: @CensiLI: I can understand this and your idea of the proof for the question is absolutely correct. But can you please direct me to the proof of the fundamental result. That will be enlightening

Comment: @Silvermoon Well, you may refer to http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf Theorem 2.3